# Delete element from indexed array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to delete element from indexed array based on value

Example:

```
var add = { number1: 'hello' , number2: "Haii", number3: "Byee" };
```

Now I want to delete element which having value Haii.

Can we do it with out iterate using for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var add = {
    number1: 'hello',
    number2: "Haii",
    number3: "Byee"
};

for (var x in add) {
    if (add[x] == "Haii") {
        add[x].remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var add = {
    number1: 'hello',
    number2: "Haii",
    number3: "Byee"
};

for (var i in add) {
    if (add[i] == "Haii") {
        delete add[i];
    }
}
```

try this:

Answer (score 1):

> Can we do it with out iterate using fir loop.

1. First, get all the keys which correspond to the value `Haii`.

   ```
   var filteredKeys = Object.keys(add).filter(function(currentKey) {
       return add[currentKey] === "Haii";
   });
   ```
2. Then, delete all those keys from `add`

   ```
   filteredKeys.forEach(function(currentKey) {
       delete add[currentKey];
   });
   ```

No explicit looping at all :-)

We can reduce the above seen two step process into a one step process, like this

```
Object.keys(add).forEach(function(currentKey) {
    if (add[currentKey] === "Haii") {
        delete add[currentKey];
    }
});
```

Again, no explicit looping :-)